# Apex How to get Lightning Tabs by App

Tags: lightning

I want to make a app launcher on Salesforce 1 which is similar to Lightning App launcher. I have obtained all the apps through AppMenultem, but do not know how to get related tabs. I searched on Google, and got this message:`List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs()`. However, this is only fit for classic version, not suitbale for Lightning version. So the issue is , how could I get the app related tabs on Lightning?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options, probably dependent on what information about the tabs you need and where your code is running:

There are SObjects [`AppDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appdefinition.htm), [`AppTabMember`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apptabmember.htm) and [`TabDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_tabdefinition.htm) which give you high level details of the Apps and Tabs.

You can use the [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm). There are calls to [Get Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_apps.htm) and [Get App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_apps_id.htm), which includes tab information.

There is a doc bug open W-5403443 which addresses the deficiency that the documentation for [Schema.describeTabs()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) does not mention that it only supports classic. Judging by the number its been around a long time so hopefully the docs will get updated soon so it's clearer.