# SOQL Query For To Get the Tabs of Particular Application

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

I want Soql Query for to get the tabs(Navigation Items) under one application (App) in salesforce. Suppose 
Application Name is Data Management under these We have Database,Table,Column tabs as Custom Objects.I want  to get the Database,Table,Column Names Using the SOQL Query.I used the SELECT AppDefinitionId,SortOrder,TabDefinitionId FROM AppTabMember WHERE AppDefinition.DurableId = '06m2w000000v8VCAAY' to get the Tab Members Name but get only Id's.Please help on this.
Thank You.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updates:**
According to this existing [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190879/apex-how-to-get-lightning-tabs-by-app), there seems to be indeed a known issue with retrieving some application and tab details using `DescribeTabsetResult` methods.

The answer in that question mentions workaround via SOQL:

First query in `AppDefinition` and filter by your application developer name and get the application `DurableId`

```
SELECT Description,DeveloperName,DurableId,Label 
FROM AppDefinition 
WHERE DeveloperName = 'YourAppDeveloperNameHere'
```

Then use the app `DurableId` to query for the app's tabs in a second SOQL on `AppTabMember`

```
SELECT AppDefinitionId,SortOrder,TabDefinitionId, TabDefinition.Name,TabDefinition.Label
FROM AppTabMember 
WHERE AppDefinition.DurableId = '06mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

`TabDefinition.Name` returns developer name of the tab

`TabDefinition.Label` returns the label of the tab

`TabDefinitionId` may also return tab name, if it matches with a standard object or standard tab like report or dashboard

References:

[AppDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appdefinition.htm)

[AppTabMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apptabmember.htm)

Comment: I know above Apex code to get the tabs particular app but in that DescribeTabsetResult method by default it taking sales application only.it not accepting any other application name.so,please help me on this. Thank You.

Comment: @Rabbani You are right. `DescribeTabsetResult` seems to have some limitations for some apps, I've found a similar question mentioning a workaround via SOQL, more details on my revised answer. Hope this helps

Comment: I want tab name of particular app but above query has Id's.please help on this.

Comment: @Rabbani you have the tab name from column TabDefinitionId when querying on AppTabMember

Comment: I am performing the salesforce to collibra integration. I want exact name of the tabs why mean I need to integrate tabs names as Domains in collibra.But I get tab Id's while integrating not changing Id's as name in collibra.Help on this .Thank for every thinking

Comment: @Rabbani Querying on `AppTabMember` shows tab name for me in column `TabDefinitionId` so not sure where exactly you are stuck. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/289295/edit) your question and provide some screenshots of the 2 SOQL results so that we see the data returned by the queries.

Comment: added the Screenshot of the what i get by sing TabMemeber query.

Comment: @Rabbani Found out that `TabDefinitionId` returns tab name if it is linked with a standard object but it returned Id in your case because tab corresponds to a custom object.  I've edited my answer again to explain how to get the tab name by traversing `TabDefinitionId` via field `TabDefinition.Label` or `TabDefinition.Name` whichever field suits your needs

Comment: yes,It is working. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Rabbani since this answer has helped resolved your question, could you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the "tick" icon next to the answer ? Marking an answer as accepted, indicates that a question is resolved and also helps other community users who might have similar question in the future. Thanks